# How to link a package with a proprietary DLL?

Tags: haskell, dll, ghc, cabal, haskell-stack

I'm writing a Haskell package which depends on a proprietary DLL. I also use `stack` tool. The library has x86 and x64 versions. According to [this issue](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1317) I can't do it by modifying `.cabal` file. So I'm trying to do it by updating `Setup.hs`. This is my setup script:

```
import Distribution.Simple
import Distribution.PackageDescription
import Distribution.Simple.LocalBuildInfo
import System.Directory

updateExtraLibDirs :: LocalBuildInfo -> IO LocalBuildInfo
updateExtraLibDirs localBuildInfo = do
    let packageDescription = localPkgDescr localBuildInfo
        test = head $ testSuites packageDescription
        testBuild = testBuildInfo  test
    dir <- getCurrentDirectory
    print $ length $ testSuites packageDescription
    return localBuildInfo {
        localPkgDescr = packageDescription {
            testSuites = [ test {
                testBuildInfo = testBuild {
                    extraLibDirs = (dir ++ "\\lib") : extraLibDirs testBuild,
                    extraLibs = ("txmlconnector64.dll") : extraLibs testBuild
                }
            } ]
        }
    }


main = defaultMainWithHooks simpleUserHooks {
          confHook = \a f -> confHook simpleUserHooks a f >>= updateExtraLibDirs
          }
```

Then I call:

```
> stack test
```

This still leads to undefined references during the test suite linkage. Why?

Comment: Something like `ghc-options: -L<path> -llib64` might work. Since you know how to compile it from the command line.. just tell cabal to do exactly that. I guess this is at most a workaround and at best an ugly hack. But things rarely play well with Windows and the FFI when it comes to the Haskell toolchain.. if the hack works for you I'd count myself lucky.

Comment: @Leonidas can you post your update as an answer and accept this to remove this from the unanswered questions queue? Thanks!

Comment: @user2407038, this does not work. Cabal can't parse file...

Comment: @sclv, I think that it is not an answer. Package is not built yet. I'm studying `Setup.hs` now, maybe it is the clue.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, I thought the update meant you solved it. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Speculative comment -- if you're getting `lib64` turning into `cabal` looking for `liblib64` what happens if you just put `64`?

Comment: @sclv, `lib` is not the actual name of the library. I should have chose something less misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just two steps:

1. Replace `"txmlconnector64.dll"` with `"txmlconnector64"`
2. In `.cabal` file set `build-type: Custom` to allow it to use your `Setup.hs`

Comment: Glad you figured this out. Do you think you ran into anything that would qualify as a bug report or feature request for cabal install? I'd be happy to do a little follow-up on reporting it if you can explain what it might be useful to add...

Comment: @sclv, such issue already exists. You can find link in the updated post.